# I want to get data between 2 dates but it is showing 1064 error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My mysql query is

```
SELECT
  testid,  
  testName, 
  DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) ,
  SUM(action=1) AS view, 
  SUM(action=2) AS start, 
  SUM(action=3) AS finish 
FROM testviewaudit 
INNER JOIN tmtests 
ON estviewaudit.testid = tmtests.tsid  
WHERE DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) >= '2016-03-12' 
AND DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) <= '2016-03-15'
GROUP BY testid;
```

Well on using the above query I am getting 1064 error

Comment: and what is the error message?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join tmtests on        testviewaudit.testid=tmtests.tsid  where action=1 o' at line 1

Comment: Write the error message into your question. However, i dont see the error. Maybe `view` or `start` making problems.

Comment: `testviewaudit` and `estviewaudit` - it's a typo. You are missing a "t". But this typo isn't in the error message!

Answer (score 0):

you just use between query

```js
 SELECT
    testid,
    testName,
    DATE(testviewaudit.datetime),
    SUM(action = 1) AS view,
    SUM(action = 2) AS start,
    SUM(action = 3) AS finish
  FROM testviewaudit INNER JOIN tmtests ON estviewaudit.testid = tmtests.tsid
  WHERE DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) between '2016-03-12'
 AND  '2016-03-15' GROUP BY testid;
```